# "Network cable unplugged" after reboot of windows computer

Tags: windows-10, networking, connection, network-adapter, cable

I have a weird behavior with my windows machine:

I recently upgraded to a new computer (namely new mainboard and cpu). In general everything is working fine but sometimes after a reboot, The computer does not have internet connection.

System:
ASUS ROG Strix X570-I Gaming (AM4, AMD X570, Mini ITX)
AMD Ryzen 9 5950X (AM4, 3.40GHz, 16-Core)

The cable is plugged in properly and routed in cable channels. There is no way of stepping over it or moving it by accident.

Unplugging and relugging the cable helps in some instances, in others it doesnt. Not replugging and resetting the network adapter helps though.

Any Ideas, what the issue could be?

I have around 7 Computers in my network, none of them show any issue with the Wired connection.

Comment: One thing to try - going into your device manager and disabling/re-enabling the network device. Does that cause it to start behaving again? Try it a few times. Not a fix for your problem, but a workaround - and if it works, it points to hardware or driver problems.

Comment: this pretty much is my current, working workaround. I guess, I ll have a look at the vendors drivers

Answer (score 1):

I meet with the same situation after upgrade to Window 10 20H2, the network icon in the bottom right corner shows network cable unplugged.

Usually, a Unplugging and re-plugging can fix issue, but I want a solution.

I change the network cable, uninstall and reinstall network adapter in device manager, execute Network Reset. Isse still appear occasionally.

Finally, use Windows installation media to clean install, then update system to the latest build, network issue doesn’t appear for three days, hope my experience can give a hint.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I will have a try of that when its starting to bother me again :D